# Ошибка при копировании файла QFile в Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Создаю файл, пишу в него текст, потом хочу скопировать. Но функция copy возвращает false. В качестве директории куда копировать в диалоге выбираю всегда:

> C:\Users\nkrivosheya\Documents\

Что я делаю не так?

```
    QFile key_file("file");
    key_file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text);
    key_file.write("test");
    key_file.flush();


    QString from_path = QDir::currentPath()  +QDir::separator()+ "file";
    qDebug() << key_file.copy(from_path, dir);
    qDebug() << key_file.errorString();
    key_file.close();
    qDebug() << key_file.copy(from_path, dir);
    qDebug() << key_file.errorString();
```

P.S. на всякий случай пробую копировать файл до его закрытия и после. Всегда ответ false.
P.S.S. `key_file.errorString();` выводит в обоих случаях: Неизвестная ошибка.

Comment: А в целевой папке случаем нет файла с таким же именем? [посмотрите] (https://doc.qt.io/QT-5/qfile.html#copy) Файл должен быть закрыт до копирования,

Comment: 1) вы вызываете статический метод, 2) что такое dir ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве аргумента для `QFile::copy` необходимо передавать полный путь к файлу, а не путь до папки.